# How to center image vertically in this RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have below layout which basically show "messages" as bubble slimier to built-in "Messages".
I just need to show also an arrow image on the right, th eimage is shown, but I need it to be centered vertically. 
I tried to add " `android:gravity="center_vertical"` to image, but it had no effect.

any clue?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/wrapper"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:background="#00DBE2ED" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/wrapper2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00DBE2ED" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/comment"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:editable="false" 
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                android:background="@drawable/bubble_yellow"
                android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                android:text="Hello bubbles!"
                android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sender"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="0dip"
                android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                android:paddingRight="2dip"
                android:text="Hello bubbles!"
                android:textColor="#b9dcdcdc"
                android:textSize="11sp"    
                android:layout_below="@+id/comment" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/aquaplayicon"
                android:src="@drawable/aquaplayicon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="onClickGirl"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:paddingRight="3dip"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" />

        </RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why do you have two LinearLayouts surrounding your RelativeLayout? These are unnecessary.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The gravity attribute is not for the layout, since that is a `LinearLayout` attribute, and your `ImageView` is inside your `RelativeLayout`. Instead, remove the line

```
android:gravity="center_vertical"
```

and add the line

```
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

Answer (score 9):

The attribute you are looking for is `android:layout_centerVertical="true"`